# how to fix undefined method `find_by_friendly_id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permalinks, slug, friendly-id

I'm trying this

```
Opportunity.find_by_friendly_id(params[:id])
```

inside a rails application with friendly_id configured. I get

```
undefined method `find_by_friendly_id' for #<Class:0x007f8060395ca0> Did you mean? find_by_sql
```

Interestingly, this works:

```
Opportunity.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Whats going on?

Here's the docs from https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb

```
# If you want to search only by the friendly id, use {#find_by_friendly_id}.
# @raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

update: someone wanted to see this:

```
$ cat components/core/app/models/opportunity.rb | grep friendly
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged
$
```

Comment: according to https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/701#issuecomment-142669074.  I can use that method

Comment: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/FriendlyId%2FFinderMethods%3Afind_by_friendly_id

Comment: why is there a -1 vote on this question, whats going on...

Comment: my bad. Will remove my comment. Please add comment if you are down voting any quesiton.

Comment: can you show your model where you have added `friendly_id`. Have you added  finders? `friendly_id :name, :use => [:slugged, :finders]`

Comment: added it to question

Comment: Your model shows you are not having `finders`

Comment: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/wiki/Friendly_id-with-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding `finders` to the model

```
friendly_id :foo, :use => [:slugged, :finders]
```